# MySql - Dynamic logic calculator

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Please find the Table " MarkCompare" below

```
SEMESTER - PAPER - TEACHER 1 - TEACHER 2
1        - ENG   - PASS      - PASS
1        - MATH  - PASS      - FAIL
2        - ENG   - PASS      - FAIL
2        - MATH  - FAIL      - FAIL
```

I want to calculate a logic like below

No.Of.Times where both teachers gave same result / sum of occurences where first teacher both the teachers result differed

I am writing a query like this

```
select count(*) from MarkCompare where teacher1=teacher2 where paper='ENG' / (select count(*) from MarkCompare where teacher1<>teacher2 where paper='ENG')
select count(*) from MarkCompare where teacher1=teacher2 where paper='MATH' / (select count(*) from MarkCompare where teacher1<>teacher2 where paper='MATH')
```

Now, in future the number of papers may increase or decrease... I am unable to find a dynamic query to run for any number of papers.

Is there a way to do this without any procedure/function, just with a query

Comment: Could you generate some expected results based on your sample data?  It appears you are after a ratio based on your queries: Same / different not just a "Sum of occurrences... not sure what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY clause to aggregate the results for each `paper` listed in the table.

```
SELECT paper,
       SUM(CASE WHEN teacher1 = teacher2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AgreeCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN teacher1 <> teacher2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DisagreeCount
    FROM MarkCompare
    GROUP BY paper;
```